# FPDF multicolumn: how to avoid multicell spliting?

Tags: php, pdf-generation, fpdf

I'm using FPDF and I took the multicolumn example from the fpdf page: http://www.fpdf.org/en/tutorial/tuto4.htm

Now I have 3 column pages where I'm printing multicell contents.
Let's say that each multicell content is a group of information that needs to be together and avoid being split on the column/page break.

How can I manage to get indivisible "boxes" of content, so if there's no space to print a box in the current column just leave the space blank and go to the next column/page to print it as one block?

[image: Example image]